# Flutter image picker Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I use image_picker_wew and this package doesnt work. After click on add image open windows explorer give me choose file, but after submit nothing happens Maybe i'm doing somthing wrong?

```dart
File _image1;
Future getImg() async {
    var tempImg = await ImagePickerWeb.getImage();
    if (tempImg != null) {
        setState(() {
            _image1 = tempImg;
            print(tempImg);
        });
    }
}
```

widget

```dart
Widget _displayChild1() {
    if (_image1 == null) {
        return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 40, 30, 40),
            child: new Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
            );
    } else {
      return Image.file(
        _image1,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        width: double.infinity,
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: tried to `print(tempImg)` before `if` statement?

Comment: i am used `print(tempImg)` before `if`statement and it print me [206, 159, 63, 47, 182, 62, 170, 135, 182, 142, 4, 50, 212, 84, 20, 88, 108, 221, 20, 197, 35, 237, 194, 136, 40,
89, 251, 104, 229, 197, 156, 69, 239, 59, 86, 108, 162, 221, 143,.....

Comment: Image(image: MemoryImage(Uint8List#106e5, scale: 1), frameBuilder: null, loadingBuilder: null, alignment: center,
semanticLabel: "office.jpg", this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)